# How can I send user to .html page within servlet if JSON response result is 0/11

Tags: java, html, json, servlets

Let's say user logs onto my site with the correct credentials which results in

```
{"ticketStatus":"Valid","requestId":"73","result":0,"resultText":"Valid"}

{"ticketStatus":"Invalid","requestId":"8","result":11,"resultText":"Invalid"}
```

How can I make it so that I can retrieve either "valid/invalid" or "0/11" so it sends the user to valid.html/invalid.html(which contains you've succesfully/unsuccesfully logged in). 
Same goes for if it's "invalid" or "11"(either one, depends on what I can assign). I just don't know how or what I should select in order to put it inside an if statement. Here's my code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //index.html form user input
     String fname = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lname");
    String ticketNummer = request.getParameter("ticketnr");

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    URL object=new URL(url);

    String ticketCheck = "{\"function\":\"Check\",\"teamId\":\"IC106-2\",\"teamKey\":\"1b3741ccf6d9ec5245055370125d901e\",\"requestId\":\""+REQ_ID+"\",\"firstName\":\""+fname+"\",\"lastName\":\""+lastName+"\",\"ticketNumber\":\""+ticketNummer+"\"}";

    System.out.println(ticketCheck);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(ticketCheck);
    writer.flush();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String jsonResponseString = sb.toString();
    JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(jsonResponseString);

    int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
    if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("" + sb.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
    }







}
```

Comment: Some details about involved services might help. My assumption is that there is a service which handles authentications and generates ticket numbers for each authentication request. After authentication request is processed the user is redirected to the service which should display the valid/invalid page based on the details retrieved from authentication service for received ticket number. If that's the case then after reading the details from authentication service (after `br.close()` line) parse the content of the `sb`, extract the status and base on the status display the corresponding page

Comment: @ValentinCarnu There's a database in which I can send the JSON string to. I can check the list with Postman, when I click login on my html site that gets opened when I run my servlet, it posts the JSON request to the url(which is somewhere in my code) which then it responds back with JSON where it checked if the user input is valid or not(gibberish = invalid, correct data what is listed when I do a post request in postman(which has the correct first name, ticketnumber and last name) = valid)). I just don't have a clue how to parse and extract the values.

Comment: Consider using an existing library to parse the json string to java objects. There are several libraries for such a use case, two popular libraries are [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Comment: Yes thanks, I found out how to parse the response I got back so this problem is solved. Only I have no clue how to give users internet access when they have a valid login.

Answer (score 0):

Question solved by parsing the response.

```
int HttpResult = con.getResponseCode();
    if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println("" + sb.toString()); //the responsemessage
    } else {
        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
    }


    String jsonStr = sb.toString();
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String ticketstat = jsonObj.getString("ticketStatus"); //get ticketStatus value
    System.out.println(ticketstat);

    if (ticketstat .equals("Invalid")){ //code here for w/e you want to do with invalid


    }

}
```